# Rails devise-jwt session storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, jwt, devise-jwt

The devise-jwt gem documentation says that if session storage is enabled, you have to skip it for jwt auth. It says that you should set on devise.rb:

```
config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth, :params_auth]
```

And you should disable :database_authenticatable. This part I quite don't understood. If in my User model, I remove :database_authenticatable, my route configured for login becomes unavailable:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/login"):

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify role_join_table_name: 'public.user_roles'
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable

  # devise :database_authenticatable,
  devise :registerable,
         :recoverable,
         :rememberable,
         :validatable,
         :jwt_authenticatable,
         jwt_revocation_strategy: Devise::JWT::RevocationStrategies::Null
end
```

devise.rb

```
config.skip_session_storage = %i[http_auth params_auth]
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  devise_for :users, defaults: { format: :json },
                     path: '',
                     path_names: {
                       sign_in: 'login',
                       sign_out: 'logout',
                       registration: 'signup'
                     },
                     controllers: {
                       sessions: 'users/sessions',
                       registrations: 'users/registrations'
                     }
end
```

What should I do to keep session, but not for jwt auth?

Comment: Hi @Samuel, I guess you are using the following gem https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt. I have used the same few days back. you don't have to remove `:database_authenticatable` from the model. just change the config file 
`config.skip_session_storage`

In a project I have to keep both session and jwt. In that case I have to add 
`Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store` in session_store.rb config file and in application_controller for `json` request had to add`'protect_from_forgery with: :null_session if request.format.json?`

Comment: I used another solution, that I posted.. Later I'll try yours.

Comment: I had the same issue. My solution was in the devise-jwt documentation.I used `self.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth, :params_auth]` on my non-API user models, so I don't skip it altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after adapting the solution I found in this article https://blog.siliconjungles.io/devise-jwt-with-sessions-hybrid, here's the answer:

**monkeypatch: config/initializers/warden/proxy.rb**

```
module Warden
  class Proxy
    def user(_argument = {})
      if request.format.json?
        return nil
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And you must have separated routes for api auth and default behavior:

**routes.rb**

```
namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      devise_scope :user do
        post 'auth/signup', to: 'registrations#create'
        post 'auth/signin', to: 'sessions#create'
        delete 'auth/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
      end
    end
  end

  devise_for :users
```

Comment: Link now goes to a shopping-website. Do you still have the original article?